# Как добавить сигнал к собственному QListWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь добавить сигнал к собственному QListWidgetItem, но ничего не работает.

```
connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(MyListBoxItem*)), this, SLOT(on_listWidgetItemClicked(MyListBoxItem*)));
```

**mylistboxhitem.h**

```
#ifndef MYLISTBOXITEM_H
#define MYLISTBOXITEM_H

#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>

class MyListBoxItem : public QListWidgetItem
{
public:
    MyListBoxItem(QListWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyListBoxItem() {};
    void setId(int id);
    int getId();
private:
    int id;
};

#endif // MYLISTBOXITEM_H
```

**mylistboxhitem.cpp**

```
MyListBoxItem::MyListBoxItem(QListWidget *parent) : QListWidgetItem(parent)
{

}

void MyListBoxItem::setId(int id)
{
    this->id = id;
}

int MyListBoxItem::getId()
{
    return this->id;
}
```

**connect**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

     // Меню  
    =================================================================================
    connect(ui->New, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionTrigger_New()));
    connect(ui->Load, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionTrigger_Load()));
    connect(ui->Save, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionTrigger_Save()));
    connect(ui->Calculate, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionTrigger_Calculate()));
    connect(ui->Exit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionTrigger_Exit()));
// =======================================================================================
// QListWidget
connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(MyListBoxItem*)), this, SLOT(on_listWidgetItemClicked(MyListBoxItem*)));
}
```

Выводит в консоль

```
No such signal QListWidget::itemClicked(MyListBoxItem*) in ...
```

Comment: Все логично, в `connect` вы передаете указатель на `QListWdget`, а нужно на `MyListBoxItem`. Плюс в вашем классе вообще нет  дополнительный сигналов.

Comment: Вы про это ui->listWidget ?

Comment: Да, про него, даже если бы вы добавили в ваш класс наследник новый сигнал, он будет не видим в базовом классе.

Comment: У `QListWidget` не сигнала с этим типом аргумента. Есть только `itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)`. Нужно сделать cast непосредственно в обработчике сигнала.